# "ERROR 1031 (HY000) at line ###: Table storage engine for '<table_name>' doesn't have this option" when creating table

Tags: mysql

When importing data exported via `mysqldump` into a new MySQL database, I get the following error on a create table statement:

`ERROR 1031 (HY000) at line ###: Table storage engine for '<table_name>' doesn't have this option`

The reference to "this option" seems pretty vague.  What's causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a table in MySQL 5.6 and earlier, the option `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` would be silently interpreted as `ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT`.  In MySQL 5.7.7 and newer with `innodb_strict_mode` enabled, the behavior is different--`FIXED` is no longer a valid value.  If a table created with `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` is exported and them imported into a MySQL 5.7.7 and newer, you'll get an error about the storage engine not having that option.

Thankfully, the fix is easy.  Change `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` to `ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT` in any SQL statements that trigger the error.  Alternatively, you could disable `innodb_strict_mode` to get the previous behavior.

See [MySQL bug #77625](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77625) for more information.